# Is it possible to add/remove Sites from AdSense via the API?

Tags: adsense, adsense-api

Is it possible to add/remove Sites from AdSense via the API? We run a CMS that includes lots of domains that point to our servers. Sites seem to get automatically added to AdSense after they get crawled, but if they leave our service the domain stays in AdSense. We'd like to run a script to prune these stale domains from our AdSense account.

Answer (score 1):

The AdSense Management API is read-only, so adding and removing sites is not supported.